# Certain Beamer themes not working in Write Latex

Tags: beamer, themes

I'm using the Beamer template provided by Write Latex:

https://www.writelatex.com/templates/2-beamer-presentation

(It's pretty basic...)

The odd thing is that when I choose certain themes (eg. Hannover, though not the default), I get an `\end{frame}` error, saying that I'm missing `$` signs.

Has anyone else encountered this? I'm giving a talk in a few days and I don't want to use the default theme.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting this problem when using WriteLaTeX, or offline?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It'll be helpful to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so that those of us who don't have accounts with WriteLaTeX can try to see if it's an issue of the codes or one with the WriteLaTeX platform.

Comment: I'm a cofounder at writeLaTeX. I have just tried our beamer template with the Hannover theme, and it seems to be working. If you send us a link to your document, we can have a look and try to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a cofounder at writeLaTeX.

After working through this with Ann, the problem turned out to be some math in a section heading that was not enclosed in dollar signs:

```
\subsection{G_0}
```

instead of

```
\subsection{$G_0$}
```

It didn't cause a problem in the default theme, because that section heading was not displayed. However, in the Hannover theme, the section heading was displayed in the side bar added by the Hannover theme.

So, for the record, it wasn't a writeLaTeX problem (phew!). Hope this helps someone else.